# Is this a gen 1 or gen 2 PS4 Controller?

Tags: ps4, controllers

So I bought this one a long time ago and I had forgotten if it is a gen 1 or 2 controller:

[image]

Is it 1st gen or 2nd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look to see if there is a light bar across the top of the touch pad. That's the only aesthetic change made to the controller, the rest is internal and latency.

If there is a light bar - gen 2. Otherwise gen 1.

Happy gaming!

Answer (score 0):

2nd generation, the d-pad is grey for the second generation. Therefore leaving the first gen with a black d-pad

Comment: Can you add details?